# Sharepoint 2010 SPLongOperation progress message does not display in Windows 7, IE 8

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint-2010, internet-explorer-8

We are testing a SharePoint 2010 web application on Windows 7 vPCs running IE8.  The application uses SPLongOperation in modal dialog boxes.  The code works fine in IE8 on Win XP service pack 3, and in IE8 directly on the Windows Server 2008 R2 web servers in the farm.  However, the dialog boxes do not display the SPLongOperation progress info in IE8 on Windows 7.  I have run script debugging IE 8 Developer Tools on Windows 7 and there are no errors that cause the code to break into the debugger.  There are no errors in the event viewers on either the client or server machines, and there's nothing in the IIS logs.

Is anyone else running into this issue?